# How to append scripts and data to existing websites?

Tags: php, url, server

I am not sure if I am asking the right question. If someone could clarify and correct this that would be welcomed! Thank you.

I stumbled upon RapGenius' (Genius) annotation service that other day and I became curious about how they implemented it on the backend. Here is an example:

Normal Webpage: http://techcrunch.com/author/josh-constine/

With RapGenius Annotation Capabilities: http://genius.it/techcrunch.com/author/josh-constine

As long as you attach genius.it before the existing URL, it is able to append annotations onto the page. What does the PHP script that handles this should look like?

I'm not exactly sure what this is called or what to Google. Could someone give me a really simple example with PHP?

Comment: How do you know Genius use PHP?

Comment: I don't and I never claimed it did. I am just familiar with PHP so I was wondering how one would go about implementing it.

Comment: then maybe you should write *What does the PHP script that handles this SHOULD look like?*.

Comment: Thanks. Is this off-topic? I'm not asking for a recommendation for any of the listed resources. I'm just curious about the name of this method and about one form of implementation. Or is my question unclear in that regard?

Comment: I would call these steps 1. page caching/mirroring/fetching/saving 2. annotation (only possible through Javascript)

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably lots of ways to achieve it. Here's one possible solution:

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    $site_html = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $html = preg_replace( '<\/body>', '<script src="myscript.js" /></body>', $site_html);
    echo $html;
?>
```

This of course assumes that all images, css and javascript in the site already in the site are linked with absolute URLs. There would probably be other hurdles to overcome if you wanted to do something like this.

Comment: Thank you! Would you happen to know what this is called? So I may look into it myself as well.

Comment: Sorry not sure what it's called. If this answered your question can you mark my question as the correct one?